# SQL to select only 1 product id if there are duplicates in order

Tags: sql

I am trying to think of how I should write this sql:

```
SELECT o.orders_id, o.customers_name, o.customers_email_address, o.orders_status, op.products_id, op.products_model
FROM orders o, orders_products op
WHERE o.orders_id = op.orders_id and o.orders_status='3'
```

What I want to accomplish is that I need a listing of product_id from each user's order. however many users order the same product twice in the same order. So what I need to do is say if it is the same order_id there and there are duplicate product_id within that order to only show the product_id once. I'm not certain how to do that..

Comment: What DBMS you're using?

Comment: Change `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT` and you should be good to go.

Comment: would something simple like `select distinct` solve this for you?

Comment: Hard to be sure without a sample of your data and desired output, but you may simply be able to group by everything in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `DISTINCT` like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.orders_id, o.customers_name, o.customers_email_address, o.orders_status, op.products_id, op.products_model
FROM orders o, orders_products op
WHERE o.orders_id = op.orders_id and o.orders_status='3'
```

However, wouldn't it be better to only have the product once and have a quantity column?

Noel

Comment: I was thinking that distinct would not work because it would select only order_ids 1 time even if there were different products but thats not how it works I guess so this is perfect. The reason I want it like this is because we are using a service to send out review requests for products so the quantity is not important at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only getting duplicates you can either add GROUP BY o.orders_id, o.customers_name, o.customers_email_address, o.orders_status, op.products_id, op.products_model

OR you can SELECT DISTINCT op.products_id